# Purging Database - Count purged/not-purged tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

So I am working with a database where I will be purging various tables that contain rows that are older than 30days. I have fairly limited knowledge of SQL and wanted to know if there was a certain way to select the row that will be purged and the rows which will not be purged. Essentially, group the rows by #ofrowspurged and #ofrowsnotpurged.

Using this information is there any way to group the rows that have a date larger than 30 days, indicating how many rows will be purged and how many will not? To be more specific, I will be inputing the table name into the SQL query so you do not need to loop through multiple tables.

Let me know if you have any questions, as this explanation may be vague. Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as posted. I think you mean you want to delete rows from a number of tables where the rows are older than 30 days. It is not at all clear how you plan on deleting that data. It also doesn't make a lot of sense that you will restrict the time for this. You either should delete the data or not. You don't want to create some bizarre procedure that does a block of work but only for a given amount of time. To answer your question, you would use a select statement to determine the tables and row counts from each.

Comment: Hey Sean thanks. You're correct, I actually meant to delete the rows in various tables where the date field was older than 30 days. As for the stored procedure I did not put it here, as I still have to create it (again still new to SQL so learning how to do this). Those variables up there are kind of my starting point, but I am not sure if they are correct. Going off what you said I would just like to count the number of rows which are older than 30 days and rows which are not, and group them so it gives me a count of rows. Would I use a count, then a select from table, and then group by?

Comment: Yes, just change the word DELETE to SELECT and will return the rows that would be deleted if you deleted them. You could use count(*) with the same from in your delete to get the row count of rows prior to deleting them.

Comment: COUNT * (SELECT * FROM [TableName] 
WHERE DateInserted < (what to put here)) GROUP BY (what to put here?) -- Could you provide some direction of what to put in the brackets?

Comment: Your statement above is a bit confusing. I don't think you want any grouping here since you want the count of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to manually run a count(*) on all of your tables filtering on the particular date field.  The reason for this is because one table might have a column "CreatedDate" that you need to check if it's >30 days old, while another might have one called "UpdatedDate" that you need to check.

However, if ALL of the tables have the same date field you are comparing on, but only differ in table name, then you can dynamically check by doing the following:

```
declare @objcursor as cursor; 

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max), @Schema sysname, @Table sysname;
SET @SQL = ''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT '''+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+
  QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+''''+
  '= COUNT(*) FROM '+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'
+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +' WHERE getDate() - [YOUR_COLUMN_NAME] >30;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
PRINT @SQL                -- test & debug
EXEC sp_executeSQL      @SQL,   -- getting variable input / setting variable output
                       ,N'@cursor cursor output', -- params definition

                        @objcursor output    -- output parameter

fetch next from @objcursor into @TableName,@Schema
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    /*Do Something With Your Table Name, eg delete, truncate, whatever*/    

fetch next from @objcursor into @Table,@Schema
end
```

Comment: Let me take a look at this and get back to you. I should have been more specific in saying that I will only run this query on one table at a time. So therefore I am looking to see how many rows will be deleted once I run this purge.

Comment: No problem that's why I left the comment in the solution.  You can actually just do a Print of the table name, and count in that comment block and get a nice little report of your tables-to-be-purged :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Would you mind writing a very rough outline so I can see exactly what functions I need to use? From my understanding it looks like I need to do COUNT * (SELECT * FROM Table_Name, WHERE DateInserted < 30 days(--not sure what condition to put here)), GROUP BY --something here

Comment: The count(*) is already done for you in the cursor. The cursor says "give me every table name where getDate() - [MY_COLUMN_NAME] > 30".  Then you can loop through that and do whatever you want. Delete from the table, truncate the table, etc.

Comment: I see, ok let me take a look at this and I'll get back to you! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You should be using DATEADD when doing math on dates.

Answer (score 2):

Still not really sure what you are trying to do but here is an example of how you can the count of rows to be deleted and then delete those rows from a specific table.

```
select COUNT(*) as NumToDelete
from MyTable
where DateInserted < DATEADD(DAY, -30, getdate())

DELETE from MyTable
where DateInserted < DATEADD(DAY, -30, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, I'll just try to add another column where it will also show me how many rows are left after deletion :)

Comment: just to double check i ran the script, and it seems its returning me 50000 rows which is my total row count for the table. However, I have dates here from 2014-03-07. Is there any reason why its not being filtered. Does the < have to be >?

Comment: Well 2014-03-07 would certainly be more than 30 days ago. :)